# PearsonR TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, anaconda

r and p using scipy calculation issue

Any idea about the type error issue?

```
r, p = pearsonr(a, b)
```

TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

sample data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmAfq.png)

```
a = DF['a']
b = DF['b']
c = DF['c']
d = DF['d']
e = DF['e']
f = DF['f']

r, p = pearsonr(a, b)
```

Comment: What are the types of `a` and `b`?  If they are numpy arrays, what are `a.dtype` and `b.dtype`.  It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that anyone can copy and run without any editing.

Comment: a b c d e f
17.5625 15.599626 99.89 62.02666 6.498 6762.109863
17.3125 5.335 100.1 25.55 6.53 6543.759766
17.5625 5.17 100.05 24.91 6.521 6567.029785
17.75 5.127 100.34 24.78 6.558 6635.439941
17.8125 5.15 100.5 24.22 6.545 6792.669922
17.4375 5.145 100.65 24.67 6.54 6838.450195

Comment: Please add that to the question.  And show the code that you use to get that data into the variables `a` and `b`.

Comment: And `DF` itself?  From the name I'd guess a Pandas dataframe create with `pd.readcsv`, but you really need to state these things clearly.  And what about the `dtype`?  You won't get very far with `scipy` without understanding what `dtypes` are.

Comment: dtype: float64; DF is dataframe with a,b,c...columns. Looking at data you may figure out that it's numerical and continuous data.

Comment: Don't be parsimonious with the information - at least not if you really want help.  `scipy` functions work with numpy arrays.  Do `np.array(b)`, and report the results - shape and dtype, maybe even some sample values.  `flexible type` means either object dtype, compound dtype (as in structured array) or string dtype.  If coming from pandas I suspect object dtype.